# Surround text with quotes python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, quotes

Hey I was wondering how I would surround text with quotes? I am copying a list of emails and I want to put them into a list but It's a pain to add quotes around each one 1 by 1. Is there anyway I can append quotes to the beginning and end of the words?

```
emails = [test1@gmail.com, test2@gmail.com,....]
```

that's what I have right now and I need to add quotes, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the inside, put it into one big string, and split it on comma-spaces.

```
>>> s = 'test1@gmail.com, test2@gmail.com'
>>> s.split(', ')
['test1@gmail.com', 'test2@gmail.com']
```

Then copy that into your source code.

(This assumes you don't have any email addresses that contain special characters - quotes, spaces, commas, and backslashes. Yes, that's allowed by the email spec, although I've never seen one in the wild.)